# Error building trees, submodule messing things up

Tags: git

I am new to git and might have messed something up along the way.

I try to use tortoisegit as much as possible because i am so used to tortoisesvn however I have also worked a bit in the git bash.

so currently I hold a directory, lets call it "project" that is a repo.
in there I have /Libs/Memflex where Memflex is a submodule linking to my fork of Memflex (on github). Took me a while to figure out that i needed a fork before clone :-)

The submodule seems to work great, however now when I try to commit my project it looks like this: http://db.tt/tknLPCSU

If one looks closer on the file list there are some files in upper section from Memflex (submodule) and the rest in non versioned

I think visuals studios new git tool did that for me. (comitted some memflex things in outer project)

however now when i click OK I get this result: http://db.tt/lXgaTkdq
So obviously git is not happy about checking in submodule things (altho some appear to already be versioned)

After some time spent googling i need some help explaining how submodule files should or should not be checked in to main project (I have pushed submodule files to my fork btw).

And how can I resolve this situation?

By simply unchecking everything in Memflex and below i got success on commit so I can work with it for now, but I would like to understand why it comes up like this and what to do about it.

should I add ignore or what to do?

Comment: No, you don't need a fork in order to clone a project from github.. just use a "read-only" url, such as the git:// or http:// ones..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you having a serious read at the [git submodules documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

It's quite easy to misinterpret the whole submodules thing, and I suspect you have; read that page and let me know if you have other questions afterwards..

Comment: Okay good news is that I had understood submodules correctly (I think ;-) Whats even better but even weirder is that when i now picked commit in tortoisegit it looked correct, no memflex files in there. So I guess tortoise got with the program all on it's own. No idea what I did except last thing i did before was manually uncheck all memflex things and commit.